# Terminal commands for VSCode plugin before clicking play, "Record at cursor", or "Record new"

Tags: visual-studio-code, playwright

When using the playwright plugin for VSCode, is there a way to run terminal commands before running a test with the play icon, "Record at cursor", or "Record new" is activated? The use case is to use commands to activate a virtual environment for other languages (python) so shell commands used in playwright don't fail.

Example: I'd like to run `poetry shell` or `source <some custom rc file>` before the test builder is run so the auth scripts that create users using a python interface don't fail because the global python version doesn't support those packages.

Things tried:

1. I have tried activating my python environment through `command + shift + p` > `Python: Select Interpreter` but that didn't work.
2. Setting "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "~/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/test-khyycDgF-py3.9/bin/python". Also didn't work.